Vue Component - dynamically create styles for deeply injected HTML content
We have content that a user creates using a text editor, which creates HTML tags for them such as h1 p etc etc.
We also let the user define a theme via a predefined form that basically sets style objects for these tags.
In Vue, you could easily add these as <h1 :style="headingTheme"></h1> attributes, but
only if Vue was creating these tags.
However, this HTML is dynamically injected to the component as a string.
At the moment, we have to create a class in the  <style> tag which binds each property individually to the theme object, like this..
<style lang="scss" scoped>

 .my_parent_class:deep(h1) {
   color: v-bind('headingTheme.color');
   font-family: v-bind('headingTheme.fontFamily');
   ... more properties here ....
 } 
    
</style>

But we have to remember to update this each time we make a change to the theme options.
Is there a way to dynamically build this css style and apply it to the Vue component?
Could use new CSSStyleSheet(), and make a sheet on the fly, but its a lot of faff.
I was wondering if there was another Vue way?
Something like the :style="themeStyle" binding, but some how cascade to any child nodes not managed by Vue!!
UPDATE
Another approach is to dynamically create a style tag:
Vue Playground
<script setup>
import { ref, computed, reactive } from 'vue'

const theme = reactive({
  color:'green'
}) 

const html = '<h1>Hello World!</h1> <h1>goodbye World!</h1>'

const style = computed(() => {
  const css = Object.entries(theme).reduce( (css, [key, value]) => {
    return css+=`${key}:${value};\n`;
  }, '');  
  return `.container h1 { ${css} }`;
});

</script>

<template>
  <!-- cant use <style> tag directly -->
  <component :is="'style'">{{ style }}</component>
  <div class="container" v-html="html"></div>

  <button @click="theme.color='blue'">Blue</button>
  <button @click="theme.color='red'">Green</button>
</template>


Only issue is that Vue does not let you make dynamic <style> tags, so you have to use <component :is="'style'">
